# What is the best way to deal with inconsistent gSSURGO data across state boundaries?

Tags: raster, data, soil

I am calculating available water content (awc) using the values aws0_999 and tk0_999a from the gSSURGO Value1 table for South Dakota and Wyoming to use in a soil water balance model (SWB) to estimate recharge. The problem is that the tk0_999a (soil thickness) values from Wyoming are orders of magnitude smaller than the South Dakota values for the same soil across the border. This will definitely affect the estimated recharge from the SWB.

Are there any suggestions on the best way to deal with this problem?

[image: mosaic raster showing the differences in gSSURGO data across the SD, WY state boundary]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates.. Unfortunately, "best" questions are too *discussion-oriented* and can't generate a correct answer, so they are often closed.  While in theory we have [chat] for these sorts of discussions, in practice Chat isn't frequented enough to generate discussion, so you might be better off looking for a true discussion forum.

Comment: This sort of edge effect is a really common problem with the gSSURGO data for a number of fields, even across county boundaries. For example, because different soil scientists have mapped different counties, you often see landform classification switch at county boundaries. In my experience, quantitative variables seem to be more consistent, because they are less subject to observer bias. I'm surprised to see this much difference in soil thickness. I contacted my State Soil Scientist at NRCS and he had some insight into how these problems are being addressed over time in the gSSURGO dataset.

Comment: Sorry if that doesn't help you much right now, but it's good to hear that the NRCS folks are aware of issues like these and are working to fix them.

Comment: Thank you, knowing that others have seen the same issue is helpful. I have reached out to the state soil scientists in WY and SD but haven't heard back. I guess the question I need to ask is how could I set the cells of the SD raster that share a boundary with WY to be equal to WY? The only way I can think of is to use the polygon layer to select all polygons along the border and change them manually which is not realistic.